# KeyError '-f' Python for LSTM model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, anaconda, lstm

Function called from embedding_matrix. Can someone please explain why I am getting this error and how I could resolve it.

```
def getEmbeddingMatrix (word_index, vectorSource):
        wordVecSources = {'fasttext' : './vectors/crawl-300d-2M-subword.vec', 'custom-fasttext' : 
           './vectors/' + '20news-fasttext.json' }
        f = open (wordVecSources[vectorSource])
        allWv = {}
        if (vectorSource == 'custom-fasttext'):
            allWv = json.loads(f.read())
        elif (vectorSource == 'fasttext'):
            errorCount = 0
            for line in f:
                values = line.split()
                word = values[0].strip()
                try:
                    wv = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
                    if (len(wv) != wvLength):
                        errorCount = errorCount + 1
                        continue
                except:
                    errorCount = errorCount + 1
                    continue
                allWv[word] = wv
            print ("# Bad Word Vectors:", errorCount)
        f.close()
        embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index)+1, wvLength))  # +1 for the masked 0
        for word, i in word_index.items():
            if word in allWv:
                embedding_matrix[i] = allWv[word]
        return embedding_matrix

early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=2, mode='auto', restore_best_weights=False)
model = keras.models.Sequential()
if (vectorSource != 'none'):
    embedding_matrix = getEmbeddingMatrix (kTokenizer.word_index, vectorSource)
    embedding = keras.layers.embeddings.Embedding(input_dim=len(kTokenizer.word_index)+1, output_dim=wvLength, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=sequenceLength, trainable=False, mask_zero=True)
else:
    embedding = keras.layers.embeddings.Embedding(input_dim=len(kTokenizer.word_index)+1, output_dim=wvLength, input_length=sequenceLength, trainable=True, mask_zero=True)
model.add(embedding)
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=150, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=False))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(numClasses, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
print(model.summary())
```

When the getEmbeddingMatrix is called it gives a KeyError '-f', even though both the files exist in the same location

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-ca6718845b1d> in <module>
      2 model = keras.models.Sequential()
      3 if (vectorSource != 'none'):
----> 4     embedding_matrix = getEmbeddingMatrix (kTokenizer.word_index, vectorSource)
      5     embedding = keras.layers.embeddings.Embedding(input_dim=len(kTokenizer.word_index)+1, output_dim=wvLength, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=sequenceLength, trainable=False, mask_zero=True)
      6 else:

<ipython-input-40-b29c56e927a3> in getEmbeddingMatrix(word_index, vectorSource)
      1 def getEmbeddingMatrix (word_index, vectorSource):
      2     wordVecSources = {'fasttext' : './vectors/crawl-300d-2M-subword.vec', 'custom-fasttext' : './vectors/' + '20news-fasttext.json' }
----> 3     f = open (wordVecSources[vectorSource])
      4     allWv = {}
      5     if (vectorSource == 'custom-fasttext'):

KeyError: '-f'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to the dictionary `wordVecSources` can either be `'fasttext'` or `'custom-fasttext'` but the key it received was `'-f'`.

This means you're somehow assigning `vectorSource` the value `'-f'` when it should be `'none'`, `'fasttext'` or `'custom-fasttext'` instead to prevent the `KeyError`.

Check the shell command-line argument which pertains to `vectorSource` in your code. For e.g., in `your_file.py` say you have `vectorSource = str(sys.argv[1])`, then you should be running something like `$python your_file.py fasttext` instead of running `$python your_file.py -f` since here the first command-line argument (sys.argv[1]) assigns `vectorSource` its value at the runtime.

Comment: I am using a jupyter notebook to write and run the code.. how do I do it in that?

Comment: @ArvindTNathan Where in the code do you define `vectorSource` ?

Comment: @ArvindTNathan just make sure `vectorSource` is only able to take 'fasttext' or 'custom-fasttext' or 'none' as values depending on what you want to achieve. I will be able to help you if you share the full code snippet.